# Misra violation with bitwise operator

Tags: c, misra

I have written the following piece of code which MISRA does not like:

```
UartPtr->C &= ((uint8_t)(~SIO_C2_SBK));
```

with

```
#define SIO_C2_SBK ((uint8_t)0x01u)
```

and `UartPtr` is defined as

```
UartPtr = (UartStruct*) 0x12345678; /* I know that this is also a violation of MISRA */
```

with the underlying datastructure:

```
typedef volatile struct UartStructTag
{
  uint8_t      BDH;
  uint8_t      BDL;
  uint8_t      C1;
  uint8_t      C2;
} UartStruct;
```

My Misra checker complains about the first line and states, that

> An integer constant expression with negative value is being converted
>   to an unsigned type.

However, the following line does not yield into a problem with MISRA:

```
UartPtr->C |= ((uint8_t)(SIO_C2_SBK));
```

So the problem comes from the bitwise negation. But as all operations are directly casted to uint8_t, i do not get the violation of the MISRA standard. Who wants to help me here?

Comment: Well, `~SIO_C2_SBK` is a negative value, so the message is factually accurate.

Comment: What version of MISRA? Which tool are you using?

Comment: @Lundin: I am using QAC 7 with MISRA 2004

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In any arithmetic expression, values of types smaller than `int` are implicitly converted to `int` before they are processed. The C language cannot do arithmetic on types smaller than `int`. Thus, your code actually behaves like this:

```
UartPtr->C &= ((uint8_t)(~(int)(uint8_t)0x01u));
```

which is just

```
UartPtr->C &= ((uint8_t)(~1));
```

where `~1` has the value `-2` on two's complement architectures.

To fix this issue, convert to `unsigned` or any other unsigned type larger than `int` before applying bitwise not:

```
UartPtr->C &= ((uint8_t)(~(unsigned)SIO_C2_SBK));
```

Comment: So is the reason for this rule that if e.g. SIO_C2_SBK would be a negative signed constant, the operation would eventually not yield the desired result and the cast would hide this?

Comment: @m47h The rule is rather trying to protect you from situations like `if(~SIO_C2_SBK > 0)` which would not behave as expected. That's one really nasty bug to track down.

Answer (score 5):

The `~` operator, like most C operators, will do an implicit integer conversion of the operand before the operator is applied.

```
#define SIO_C2_SBK ((uint8_t)0x01u)
```

So the above macro is the issue, because you are forcing the literal down from `unsigned int` type into a small integer type, which will get implicitly promoted. Instead of `uint8_t` you end up with `int`, before `~` is applied.

This violates rule 10.1 of MISRA-C:2004, which doesn't allow implicit conversions that yield a type of different signedness (such conversions are dangerous, so it is a very good rule).

- If you don't need this macro to give `uint8_t`, then simply drop the `(uint8_t` cast and that will solve the problem.
- If this macro for some reason must give `uint8_t`, then change the code to this (MISRA compliant):

  ```
  UartPtr->C &= (uint8_t) ~(uint32_t)SIO_C2_SBK;
  ```

  where `uint32_t` corresponds to the size of `int` on the given platform.

Comment: I am not terribly familiar with MISRA, but does it not require masking with `& 0xFF` before casting with `uint8_t`?

Comment: @user694733 Nope. Masking with `& 0xFF` is essentially the same thing as casting to `uint8_t`. However, MISRA 10.5 explicitly requires you to cast the result of the `~` operator to the intended type.